# Grep can't use -B with -v

Tags: grep

Say I have `file`:

```
cat
dog
bird
```

If I run `cat file | grep dog -B 1` I get:

```
cat
dog
```

If I run `cat file | grep dog -v` I get:

```
cat
bird
```

I would expect `cat file | grep dog -v -B 1` to return `bird` but instead it just acts like `grep dog` without any flags.

Why can't I use these flags together?

*grep (GNU grep) 2.16, also tested on 2.25 with same results*

Comment: Which grep? GNU grep 3.1 gives me all three lines in the output, as expected.

Comment: @muru Shouldn't `cat file | grep dog -v -B 1` return just `bird` instead of all three lines? I'm using 2.16.

Comment: Why only `bird`? It should of course return `cat` (and since there's nothing before it, nothing more for `cat`), and for `bird`, `bird` and the line above it, which is `dog`, hence, all three lines.

Comment: Compare: `(seq 1 5; seq 5 10) | grep 5 -B 1 -v` skips the first `5` in the output for me.

Comment: How about this: `cat test.txt| grep dog -A 1 | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}'`

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add my solution to get the inverse of `grep dog -B 1`:

```
cat file | grep "$(cat file | grep dog -B 1)" -v
```

Which returns `bird` the opposite of what `cat file | grep dog -B 1` produces.

*It seems my original problem was just misunderstanding how this should work. I was thinking applying `-v` would simply inverse any `grep` command.*

*In actuality it seems the `-v` flag was run first and then `-B 1` is applied after, so all lines not containing `dog` are returned and then all lines 1 before those lines, meaning all lines.*

---

Edit: I realized this solution is wrong. It doesn't inverse because the second grep using the sub-shell doesn't treat `"$(cat file | grep dog -B 1)"` as a single text block. Instead each line generated is treated as a different grep.

If the subshell includes:

```
cat
dog
```

And the original file includes other instances of `cat` that aren't 1 position before `dog` they will be removed to with this solution.

Comment: @don_crissti looks like OP wants `-A1`, but without the line that matched.

Comment: @don_crissti I simply want to return the opposite of grep commands using -A -B or -C flags. Whatever text a `grep -B $n` produces I want all lines that weren't shown instead of those that were. Does that make sense?

Comment: @don_crissti closed